# Do the Lord of glory in 1 Corinthians and the King of glory in Psalm 24 have the same referent?

Tags: 1-corinthians, psalms, referent-identification

Psalm 24:7-10 says:

> Lift up your heads, O ye gates; and be ye lift up, ye everlasting doors; and the King of glory shall come in. Who is this King of glory? The LORD strong and mighty, the LORD mighty in battle. Lift up your heads, O ye gates; even lift them up, ye everlasting doors; and the King of glory shall come in. 
> Who is this King of glory? The LORD of hosts, he is the King of glory. Selah.

and it is made clear that this "King of glory" is the Lord of hosts.

1 Corinthians 2:7-8 says:

> But we speak the wisdom of God in a mystery, even the hidden wisdom, which God ordained before the world unto our glory: Which none of the princes of this world knew: for had they known it, they would not have crucified the Lord of glory.

and in this context it is clear that the Lord of glory is Jesus Christ prior to his crucifixion, death, burial, and ascension.

Are King (מלך) and Lord (κύριος) synonymous such that the "King of glory" and the "Lord of glory" have the same referent?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the JPS translation of the Tanak, Psalm 24:7-10.  I added Hebrew words om [].

```
  7 O gates, lift up your heads! 
  Up high, you everlasting doors, 
     so the King of glory may come in! 
  8 Who is the King of glory?— 
     the LORD [יְ֭הוָה], mighty and valiant, 
     the LORD [יְ֝הוָ֗ה], valiant in battle. 
  9 O gates, lift up your heads! 
  Lift them up, you everlasting doors, 
     so the King of glory may come in! 
  10 Who is the King of glory?— 
     the LORD [יְהוָ֥ה] of hosts, 
     He is the King of glory!
```

Thus, the King of glory in Psalm 24:7-10 is unmistakably God, with LORD translating the divine name.

Thus, Paul definitely referred to Jesus when he used the term *crucified*, and "Lord of glory" does seem to point back to Psalm 24:7-10.

> 7 But we impart a secret and hidden wisdom of God, which God decreed before the ages for our glory. 8 None of the rulers of this age understood this, for if they had, they would not have crucified the Lord of glory.
> (1 Cor. 2:7–8, ESV)

Thus, is Paul calling Jesus God?

Note James also calls Jesus the Lord of glory.

> My brothers, show no partiality as you hold the faith in our Lord Jesus Christ, the Lord of glory.
> (James 2:1, ESV)

There isn't enough evidence to keep those who want to double the connection from doing so, but the evidence does point to Paul identifying Jesus Christ as God through the divine name.

**Commentary**

> “The Lord of glory.”—So also in Jas. 2:1. This expression is not to be taken as equivalent to ‘glorious Lord,’ but, as in the analogous expressions, “Father of glory” (Eph. 1:17); “The God of glory” (Acts 7:2), “The Lord is the possessor of glory.” The genitive case used here in the Greek is the genitive of possession. “Lord of glory” is a title of Divinity. It means possessor of Divine excellence. “Who is the King of glory? The Lord of hosts, he is the King of glory” (Ps. 24:10; Acts 7:2; Jas. 2:1; Eph. 1:17). The person crucified, therefore, was a Divine person.
> --
> Lange, J. P., Schaff, P., Kling, C. F., & Poor, D. W. (2008). *A commentary on the Holy Scriptures: 1 Corinthians* (p. 58). Logos Bible Software.

> “the Lord of glory” This phrase is used of YHWH in Acts 7:2; Eph. 1:17. A similar phrase is used of Jesus in James 2:1. This is another example of NT authors using a title of YHWH for Jesus and thereby asserting His equality with YHWH (cf. 2 Cor. 4:6).
> --
> Utley, R. J. (2002). *Paul’s Letters to a Troubled Church: I and II Corinthians*: Vol. Volume 6 (p. 35). Bible Lessons International.

> **Lord of glory** is as august a statement as Paul will ever make in reference to Christ, assigning to him a predicate which Old Testament faith had reserved for God, for describing the “weight” [“glory,” Hebrew: kabod] of God’s appearance, experienced as honor, might, or brilliance).
> --
> Harrisville, R. A. (1987). *I Corinthians* (p. 52). Augsburg Publishing House.

**P.S.**

This seems to be the verse Paul quoted in 2:9.  Surprising enough the Jewish translation is closer to Paul than Christian translations.

```
  Such things had never been heard or noted. 
  No eye has seen [them], O God, but You, 
  Who act for those who trust in You.
           (Isa. 64:3, JPS Tanakh)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Psalm 24:7] reflects the event of [1 Chronicles 15] when King David escorted into Zion's gates the Ark called also by the Name of King YHVH [1 Samuel 6:2] "Ark of God, which is called a Name, the Name of YHVH of Hosts who dwell upon the Keruvim" ( אֲר֣וֹן הָאֱלֹהִ֔ים אֲשֶׁר־נִקְרָ֣א שֵׁ֗ם שֵׁ֣ם יְהֹוָ֧ה צְבָא֛וֹת ישֵׁ֥ב הַכְּרֻבִ֖ים ).

Based on the first phrase of [Psalm 24] "Of-David" לְדָוִד the author is King David (who never saw Solomon's construction of the 1st Temple) invalidating interpretations by commentators Rashi & Radak who try to ascribe the events of [Psalm 24:7] to Solomon escorting the Ark in the Temple gates.

In [Psalm 24:10] King David asks the Israelites the Name of their true King : "Who is this King of Glory?"

> David declares to Israel the Name of their true King : "YHVH of Hosts" ( יְהֹוָה צְבָאוֹת ) - "He is the King of Glory forever" ( ה֚וּא מֶלֶךְ הַכָּבוֹד סֶֽלָה ).

Since YHVH is [always] סֶֽלָה [a] אֱלֹהִים חַיִּים וּמֶ֣לֶךְ [Living God & King] of the world - Jeremiah 10:10, then YHVH could not have changed from eternally Living חַיִּים to dying as a crucified king of 1 Corinthians 2:8.

Comment: What is the assertion that Psalm 24 reflects 1 Chronicles 15 founded upon?